# Different Css3 border style

Tags: css

I want to add a border style in my content heading like this
[image]

Can I make it using css3? If any one know this how to do this please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very "hard-coded" solution but I got something to work.

You have to set the `mainDiv` hiding the left and right borders the same as the body color on your webpage.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.mainDiv {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #CCAC00;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3em;
}

.mainDiv:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 35px;
  top: 5px;
  left: -1px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.mainDiv:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 35px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 31.2em;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpwzL7nb/) if you want to edit it to your liking.

Comment: Thanks @ryantpayton you are really genius. Thanks a Lot :)

Comment: @ShariarHossain Glad to hear it! :)